# Facebook iframe application issue

Tags: c#-4.0, facebook

I have developed a face book iframe application in .net c#.First time when user access iframe application [image]

it shows this window but it should ask for permission & allow user to access my app.
When i click go to face book.com it shows permission window.after that when i choose allow its redirecting me to my canvas URL out side the face book.when i try to access 2nd time its working fine.The issue is that for every first time user who want to access the app ist shows the existing window.Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your code?  It will be a lot easier to assist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figure it out.@pastylegs said right.Thanks for your answers.Let me elaborate it.Most of developer just redirecting to specific url so you have to redirect on top  window.

1)if you are using a tag so use target=_blank.

2)If your are using any other thing to redirect in any technology so just use

top.location.href='" + codedataurl + "'

where codedataurl is your facebook authentication url which contains client id,redirect url & all.

I hope it will help you guys.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using iframes, you need to make sure that when you redirect the user to the authorization dialog, you do so on the top window of the users browser. You can do this using javascript (instead of just a redirect URL).

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/#auth

Maybe this is the problem?